# Flip box hover with image as background

Tags: html, css

im using a flip box with a front and back content when i hover  (rotateY(180deg)) . that worked for simple container (only text) but didn't work when the background was an image this is my first time using nth-child element so any advises are welcome^^.
(its a small screen version for now)
and thanks in advance.

```css
/*
=============== 
SERVICES
===============
*/
.title-service {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.title-service p {
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.container-service {
  width: 70vh;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
.container-service:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-card {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.back-card {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.container-service h3 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.container-service i {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
}
.container-service:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(../Responsive\ Website/img-2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.container-service:nth-child(3) .front-card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.dev h3 {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.dev i {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
    <!-- START SERVICES -->
    <section class="service">
      <div class="info-service">
        <div class="title-service">
          <h1>SERVICES</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-service web">
          <div class="front-card">
            <span><i class="fas fa-palette"></i></span>
            <h3>Web Design</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back-card">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero
              maxime, reiciendis, ut earum amet architecto, cum magni cumque eum
              repudiandae a minus sunt! Sed porro expedita, fuga aspernatur
              molestiae iste ab cupiditate repudiandae cumque officia ea.
              Tenetur amet ullam voluptatum?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-service f-e">
          <div class="dev">
            <div class="front-card">
              <span><i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i></span>
              <h3>Front Dev</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="back-card">
              <h3>Front Dev</h3>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit
                optio, eum esse doloremque molestias aspernatur.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-service branding">
          <div class="front-card">
            <span><i class="fas fa-building"></i></span>
            <h3>Branding</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="back-card">
            <h3>Branding</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Consequuntur, error.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END SERVICES -->
```

Comment: Have you tried nth-of-type instead of nth-child? I didn't quite understand where you want the image as background but I don't think nth-child works as I'm assuming you want since nth-child as the name indicates needs to refer to the parent and container-service is not it... More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: i want the image as background of the card ( container) the text dont show up only the img did rotate

Answer (score 0):

The front and back are stacked above the parent wrapper and have inherited the parent background color, try applying the image to the front card of the third child.